# Rappelling or abseiling?

Tags: support, tags, tag-synonyms

I was recently reading [this article](http://www.ukclimbing.com/articles/page.php?id=167) and it had an interesting insight that I think is relevant to us:

> Why do American climbers call it “Rappelling”?
>
> They chose the French
> term for sliding down a rope whereas we chose the German. Nothing more
> to it than that.

Now we have two tags [rappelling](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rappelling) and [abseiling](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/abseiling) not to mention [abseil](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/abseil) (though this one should disappear soon). What do we do about this? What's SE's policy on this kind of thing?

Comment: We can set as synonyms. Doesn't really matter which is the master.

Comment: I thought synonyms were eventually merged @RoryAlsop?

Comment: Often, but not  mandatory :-)

Answer (score 3):

I think it would be good to set them as synonyms. It might help prevent confusion, since it is not necessarily clear to everyone that both things mean the same.